# Approval process: Approve for people below

Tags: approval-process

**Scenario**

- There are two roles in the system: "Supervisor" and below "Worker"
- An agent is part of the "Worker" role and is set as the approver for a record

**Question**

- Is a user with supervisor role able to approve the record for a worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard Approval Process, due to role-hierarchy the user in higher role is able to approve requests waiting in the queue of the user below the role.

So the User with Supervisor role is able to approve the record for user with Worker role.